# Vaadin: Error when deploy to wildfly(debian). How do I configure vaadin?

Tags: debian, wildfly, vaadin

I am trying to deploy spring boot+vaadin 14 application on wildfly 20 installed on debian. I get an error - I can't write the package.json file

```
Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:2.0.2.Final:deploy (default-cli) on project admin:
Failed to execute goal deploy: {"WFLYCTL0062: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:
" => {"Operation step-1" => {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" 
=> {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"admin.war\".undertow-deployment" => 
"java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.io.IOException: 
File '/home/gitlab-runner/builds/a41nNuzA/0/...../package.json' cannot be written to
```

Where is he trying to write it down? How do I configure vaadin?

Comment: You are deploying in development mode. Is this on purpose? Otherwise you have to build it in production mode. Please see https://vaadin.com/docs/flow/production/tutorial-production-mode-basic.html

Comment: This is because this is a test virtual server and I didn't get this error on wildfly on windows 10.

Comment: Thank you! It,s solved this problem.

Comment: That's great. I will add this as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to deploy to a server you should build the Vaadin app in production mode.

```
mvn clean deploy -Pproduction
```

Please find more information here:

https://vaadin.com/docs/flow/production/tutorial-production-mode-basic.html